# Google maps Snap to road demo not working | Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to get the Snap to Road demo working that is supplied [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) but I keep getting the error:  Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError. I already searched around and this is the error Google gives you for either supplying no key or a invalid key but even if I generate a brand new key it won't work. It just gives me a blank screen.

Why is it throwing this error even though I supply the code with the API key?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Roads API Demo</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
    
    #panel {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -180px;
      z-index: 5;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    
    #bar {
      width: 240px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      margin: 8px;
      padding: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    #autoc {
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places"></script>
  <script>
    var apiKey = 'AIzaSyB3kpx3fgR9VT3WL2tp49QrbnyDdgygGeo';

    var map;
    var drawingManager;
    var placeIdArray = [];
    var polylines = [];
    var snappedCoordinates = [];

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: {
          lat: -33.8667,
          lng: 151.1955
        }
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

      // Adds a Places search box. Searching for a place will center the map on that
      // location.
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(
        document.getElementById('bar'));
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('autoc'));
      autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);
        }
      });

      // Enables the polyline drawing control. Click on the map to start drawing a
      // polyline. Each click will add a new vertice. Double-click to stop drawing.
      drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
          ]
        },
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: '#696969',
          strokeWeight: 2
        }
      });
      drawingManager.setMap(map);

      // Snap-to-road when the polyline is completed.
      drawingManager.addListener('polylinecomplete', function(poly) {
        var path = poly.getPath();
        polylines.push(poly);
        placeIdArray = [];
        runSnapToRoad(path);
      });

      // Clear button. Click to remove all polylines.
      $('#clear').click(function(ev) {
        for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; ++i) {
          polylines[i].setMap(null);
        }
        polylines = [];
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    }

    // Snap a user-created polyline to roads and draw the snapped path
    function runSnapToRoad(path) {
      var pathValues = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
        pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue());
      }

      $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
        interpolate: true,
        key: apiKey,
        path: pathValues.join('|')
      }, function(data) {
        processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
        drawSnappedPolyline();
        getAndDrawSpeedLimits();
      });
    }

    // Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road service.
    function processSnapToRoadResponse(data) {
      snappedCoordinates = [];
      placeIdArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
          data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
          data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
        snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
        placeIdArray.push(data.snappedPoints[i].placeId);
      }
    }

    // Draws the snapped polyline (after processing snap-to-road response).
    function drawSnappedPolyline() {
      var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: snappedCoordinates,
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWeight: 3
      });

      snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
      polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
    }

    // Gets speed limits (for 100 segments at a time) and draws a polyline
    // color-coded by speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road
    // response.
    function getAndDrawSpeedLimits() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= placeIdArray.length / 100; i++) {
        // Ensure that no query exceeds the max 100 placeID limit.
        var start = i * 100;
        var end = Math.min((i + 1) * 100 - 1, placeIdArray.length);

        drawSpeedLimits(start, end);
      }
    }

    // Gets speed limits for a 100-segment path and draws a polyline color-coded by
    // speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road response.
    function drawSpeedLimits(start, end) {
      var placeIdQuery = '';
      for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
        placeIdQuery += '&placeId=' + placeIdArray[i];
      }

      $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits',
        'key=' + apiKey + placeIdQuery,
        function(speedData) {
          processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start);
        }
      );
    }

    // Draw a polyline segment (up to 100 road segments) color-coded by speed limit.
    function processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start) {
      var end = start + speedData.speedLimits.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < speedData.speedLimits.length - 1; i++) {
        var speedLimit = speedData.speedLimits[i].speedLimit;
        var color = getColorForSpeed(speedLimit);

        // Take two points for a single-segment polyline.
        var coords = snappedCoordinates.slice(start + i, start + i + 2);

        var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: coords,
          strokeColor: color,
          strokeWeight: 6
        });
        snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
        polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
      }
    }

    function getColorForSpeed(speed_kph) {
      if (speed_kph <= 40) {
        return 'purple';
      }
      if (speed_kph <= 50) {
        return 'blue';
      }
      if (speed_kph <= 60) {
        return 'green';
      }
      if (speed_kph <= 80) {
        return 'yellow';
      }
      if (speed_kph <= 100) {
        return 'orange';
      }
      return 'red';
    }
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      initialize
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="bar">
    <p class="auto"><input type="text" id="autoc" /></p>
    <p><a id="clear" href="#">Click here</a> to clear map.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you haven't got an API KEY:**
The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key.

Step 1: Get a Key from this URL

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Step 2: Include your script with the API KEY

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or replace

```
 var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
```

**If you got an API KEY**
Google maps Snap to Road demo

Full Code

```css
 html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }

      #bar {
        width: 240px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
        margin: 8px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      #autoc {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Roads API Demo</title>
    <script       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/_static/js/jquery-bundle.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places"></script>
    <script>
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyB3kpx3fgR9VT3WL2tp49QrbnyDdgygGeo';

var map;
var drawingManager;
var placeIdArray = [];
var polylines = [];
var snappedCoordinates = [];

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: -33.8667, lng: 151.1955}
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  // Adds a Places search box. Searching for a place will center the map on that
  // location.
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(
      document.getElementById('bar'));
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autoc'));
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
  });

  // Enables the polyline drawing control. Click on the map to start drawing a
  // polyline. Each click will add a new vertice. Double-click to stop drawing.
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
      ]
    },
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: '#696969',
      strokeWeight: 2
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  // Snap-to-road when the polyline is completed.
  drawingManager.addListener('polylinecomplete', function(poly) {
    var path = poly.getPath();
    polylines.push(poly);
    placeIdArray = [];
    runSnapToRoad(path);
  });

  // Clear button. Click to remove all polylines.
  $('#clear').click(function(ev) {
    for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; ++i) {
      polylines[i].setMap(null);
    }
    polylines = [];
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
}

// Snap a user-created polyline to roads and draw the snapped path
function runSnapToRoad(path) {
  var pathValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
    pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue());
  }

  $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
    interpolate: true,
    key: apiKey,
    path: pathValues.join('|')
  }, function(data) {
    processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
    drawSnappedPolyline();
    getAndDrawSpeedLimits();
  });
}

// Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road service.
function processSnapToRoadResponse(data) {
  snappedCoordinates = [];
  placeIdArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
        data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
    snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
    placeIdArray.push(data.snappedPoints[i].placeId);
  }
}

// Draws the snapped polyline (after processing snap-to-road response).
function drawSnappedPolyline() {
  var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: snappedCoordinates,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
  polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
}

// Gets speed limits (for 100 segments at a time) and draws a polyline
// color-coded by speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road
// response.
function getAndDrawSpeedLimits() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= placeIdArray.length / 100; i++) {
    // Ensure that no query exceeds the max 100 placeID limit.
    var start = i * 100;
    var end = Math.min((i + 1) * 100 - 1, placeIdArray.length);

    drawSpeedLimits(start, end);
  }
}

// Gets speed limits for a 100-segment path and draws a polyline color-coded by
// speed limit. Must be called after processing snap-to-road response.
function drawSpeedLimits(start, end) {
    var placeIdQuery = '';
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
      placeIdQuery += '&placeId=' + placeIdArray[i];
    }

    $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits',
        'key=' + apiKey + placeIdQuery,
        function(speedData) {
          processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start);
        }
    );
}

// Draw a polyline segment (up to 100 road segments) color-coded by speed limit.
function processSpeedLimitResponse(speedData, start) {
  var end = start + speedData.speedLimits.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < speedData.speedLimits.length - 1; i++) {
    var speedLimit = speedData.speedLimits[i].speedLimit;
    var color = getColorForSpeed(speedLimit);

    // Take two points for a single-segment polyline.
    var coords = snappedCoordinates.slice(start + i, start + i + 2);

    var snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: coords,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 6
    });
    snappedPolyline.setMap(map);
    polylines.push(snappedPolyline);
  }
}

function getColorForSpeed(speed_kph) {
  if (speed_kph <= 40) {
    return 'purple';
  }
  if (speed_kph <= 50) {
    return 'blue';
  }
  if (speed_kph <= 60) {
    return 'green';
  }
  if (speed_kph <= 80) {
    return 'yellow';
  }
  if (speed_kph <= 100) {
    return 'orange';
  }
  return 'red';
}

$(window).load(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="bar">
      <p class="auto"><input type="text" id="autoc"/></p>
      <p><a id="clear" href="#">Click here</a> to clear map.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I followed the steps that are on the snap to road page. Got a key from the exact link you just gave me and i still get the same result. What exactly am i missing?

Comment: Check the snippet I attached. I referred following URL https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo

Comment: if i copy your exact code it still does not work. Even though it works in the snippet

Comment: Maybe something else is blocking it, in your source. Can be some imports, other scripts

Comment: Could it be that i am hosting it locally?

Comment: How do you host it locally? with some local web server? such as mamp or xampp?

Comment: I use MAMP to host the website.

Comment: I got it to work. I do not know what i changed or what i did but it works now.

Comment: That's great, it happened to me once, anyways it would be great if you can help me by upvoting and selecting the answer if it helped you

Comment: Is there a way to improve this? Because i have been trying out the routes and it is wierd as heck when you click a bit further than the codes liking.